# Grafana installed on kubernated web href not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, grafana, kubectl, kubernetes-helm

I have installed Grafana from this git repo [Grafana-Kubernates](https://github.com/ibrahiem94/prometheus-kubernetes).
After the installation, Grafana web monitor link is available at `{aws LB}/api/v1/namespaces/monitoring/services/grafana/proxy`. But when I navigate to any link, it is redirected to `{aws LB}/{service like dashboard or datasource}` insted of `{aws LB}/api/v1/namespaces/monitoring/services/grafana/proxy/{dashboard or datasource}`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

> how can I solve this?

Exposing functionality outside of the cluster is designed to be done with either a `Service` of type `LoadBalancer`, where kubernetes will create the ELB on your behalf, or with an `ingress-controller` such that you only have to have a single TCP/IP port or ELB but that dispatches to all the `Service`s in the cluster based on `Host:` header virtual-hosting.

In short, you are trying to use `kubectl` in a manner that it wasn't designed to be used.

Comment: I have made already the service type of LoadBalancer but still not working

Comment: maybe so, but based on the URL you put in your question, it's pointing to the kubernetes api server, and not to the grafana pods since I am about 99.999999% certain grafana's api urls do not contain `/api/v1/namespaces` etc; what your `Service` should be pointing to is the http port with a selector that matches the grafana pods